# Download specific openstack milestone

Tags: cloud, openstack, devstack

I'm trying to download a specific openstack milestone (Kilo version) via Devstack. I created a local.conf file in devstack folder and added this lines as suggested by the [official Devstack site](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/faq.html#how-do-i-run-a-specific-openstack-milestone):

```
[[local|localrc]]
GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/kilo
HORIZON_BRANCH=stable/kilo
KEYSTONE_BRANCH=stable/kilo
NOVA_BRANCH=stable/kilo
GLANCE_BRANCH=stable/kilo
NEUTRON_BRANCH=stable/kilo
SWIFT_BRANCH=2.3.0
```

But when I check for the installed version of nova I got "12.0.0." - which represent the unstable version Liberty.
What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an easier way: I just use

> git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack -b stable/kilo

and now I got a "2015.1.2" version which it refers to Kilo

Answer (score 0):

The configuration options you are showcasing, are to switch between the branches of the repository or the tags (I am not completely for the later)

If you want to switch to a specific milestone or changes, some additional micro-configuration is need as showcased in [stackrc - DevStack Settings](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/stackrc.html#stackrc-devstack-settings)

The code bellow (quoting the example of the official resource) will 'download' a specific Gerrit review to run for nova

```
NOVA_REPO=https://review.openstack.org/p/openstack/nova
NOVA_BRANCH=refs/changes/50/5050/1
```